# Can any one help i found local.error: unsupported local setting

Tags: python, automation, pdf-generation

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import locale
import sys
import emails
import os
import reports


def load_data(filename):
    """Loads the contents of filename as a JSON file."""
    with open(filename) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    return data


def format_car(car):
    """Given a car dictionary, returns a nicely formatted name."""
    return "{} {} ({})".format(car["car_make"], car["car_model"], car["car_year"])


def process_data(data):
    """Analyzes the data, looking for maximums.
      Returns a list of lines that summarize the information.
    """
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')
    max_revenue = {"revenue": 0}
    max_sales = {"total_sales": 0}
    years_count = {}
    for item in data:
        # Calculate the revenue generated by this model (price * total_sales)
        # We need to convert the price from "$1234.56" to 1234.56
        item_price = locale.atof(item["price"].strip("$"))
        item_revenue = item["total_sales"] * item_price
        if item_revenue > max_revenue["revenue"]:
            item["revenue"] = item_revenue
            max_revenue = item

        # also handle max sales
        if item["total_sales"] > max_sales["total_sales"]:
            max_sales = item

        # also handle most popular car_year
        if item["car"]["car_year"] in years_count:
            years_count[item["car"]["car_year"]] = {"count": years_count[item["car"]["car_year"]]["count"]+1, "total_sales": years_count[item["car"]["car_year"]]["total_sales"]+item["total_sales"]}
        else:
            years_count[item["car"]["car_year"]] = {"count": 1, "total_sales": item["total_sales"]}

    popular_year = sorted(years_count.items(),key=lambda x: x[1]["count"], reverse=True)[0]
    summary = ["The {} generated the most revenue: ${}".format(format_car(max_revenue["car"]), max_revenue["revenue"]),
                "The {} had the most sales: {}".format(format_car(max_revenue["car"]), max_sales["total_sales"]),
                "The most popular year was {} with {} sales.".format(popular_year[0],popular_year[1]["total_sales"])]

    return summary


def cars_dict_to_table(car_data):
    """Turns the data in car_data into a list of lists."""
    table_data = [["ID", "Car", "Price", "Total Sales"]]
    for item in car_data:
        table_data.append([item["id"], format_car(item["car"]), item["price"], item["total_sales"]])
    return table_data


def main(argv):
    """Process the JSON data and generate a full report out of it."""
    data = load_data("../car_sales.json")
    summary = process_data(data)
    print(summary)
    # turn this into a PDF report
    table_data = cars_dict_to_table(data)
    reports.generate("/tmp/cars.pdf", "Sales summary for last month", "<br/>".join(summary), table_data)

    # send the PDF report as an email attachment
    sender = "automation@example.com"
    receiver = "{}@example.com".format(os.environ.get('USER'))
    subject = "Sales summary for last month"
    body = "\n".join(summary)

    message = emails.generate(sender, receiver, subject, body, "/tmp/cars.pdf")
    emails.send(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

local.error:unsupported local setting means locale file are n't present
first run command :
`locale -a`  on bash shell  they will provide present file

`C`
`C.UTF-8`
`POSIX`

edit the above given code :`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')`
new code: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'C.UTF-8')`